# Learn CoreFoundation

Tags: c, cocoa, core-graphics, cfnetwork

I'd like to know how some developers achieve amazing functionality with core technologies. My education in programming was based only in high level programming languages like c# and java and I find very hard to "go way back" and learn c based technologies like core graphics, also the thing is that I can find books that teach you core graphics but can't find any on core foundation, so, when I read about peer to peer and socket topics I feel lost because the CFNetwork header file isn't enough for somebody without experience in unix sockets.
So , back to the question, what kind of resources should I look for, to learn core foundation and then CFNetwork?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's website is full of documentation on a lot of its technologies. For example, the first result on a Google search for "CFNetwork" is [the CFNetwork Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/).

It's really not all that different. Be careful not to psych yourself out. CoreFoundation was even intentionally modeled after the Objective-C Foundation framework.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've been thinking about it and even though it's hard to learn ansi c, everything valuable in life has a cost ...